# querySelectorAll for selector "not" does not work on IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

On IE 8, this script produces error:

```
var ygakandiuppercase = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]:not(.noupper)');
```

But if I remove "not" clause like this:

```
var ygakandiuppercase = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
```

its work on IE 8.

How to select text input element, except for specified class name?

Comment: Use jQuery/Sizzle and stop thinking about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)** will work in IE8 only with css2 selectors and below. **[:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot)** is a css3 specification. Hence your first script fails in IE8. You can wither use plugins like **[jquery](http://jquery.com/)** which will cover up with cross browser issues or use traditional selector and filter them out manually.